# Htaccess - How to remove path without query string after last slash on url

Tags: apache, redirect

I'd like to remove path without query string after last slash on url.

For example, there is a url:
`https://www.example.com/example.php/fakepath/fakepath2/fakepath3?id=123`

I want to add a rewrite rule in `.htaccess` file, and redirect origin url to this url:
`https://www.example.com/example.php?id=123`

Becasue I found this issue:

This is a correct url: http://www.twhappy.com/index.php?action=blog&category=6

If I add slash after `index.php`, the url will be http://www.twhappy.com/index.php/?action=blog&category=6

If I add fake path after `index.php`:

http://www.twhappy.com/index.php/?action=blog&category=6
http://www.twhappy.com/index.php/fakepath/?action=blog&category=6
http://www.twhappy.com/index.php/fakepath/fakepath2/fakepath3/?action=blog&category=6

These url can be visit after I added fake path.

So, I want a rewrite rule to redirect them to correct url.

Is there have any idea for this case?

Thanks you so much.

Comment: _"These url can be visit after I added fake path"_ <- why is this a problem? If you don't want to support PATH_INFO urls, disabled it with `AcceptPathInfo Off`. Users attempting weird URLs will get a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATED ANSWER

Here's a [`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) rule from `mod_alias` that should strip any `PATH_INFO` from `.php` files. This should perform the redirect you're after

```
# .htaccess
RedirectMatch permanent "^(.*\.php)/.*" "$1"
```

---

#### Old answer(s) below

You certainly don't need `mod_rewrite` for this. Instead, enable [`AcceptPathInfo`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo), eg

```
# .htaccess
AcceptPathInfo On
```

Then, requests for `/example.php/fakepath/fakepath2/fakepath3?id=123` will resolve to `example.php` with

```
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
```

producing

```
array(1) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(123)
}
string(19) "/fakepath/fakepath2/fakepath3"
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to support URLs with `PATH_INFO`, you can turn it off with

```
# .htaccess
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

then requests for URLs that contain `PATH_INFO` will result in a 404.

Comment: Phil, thank you for your patience.
But this solution is not what I want.
I want a rewrite rule, redirect  `https://www.example.com/example.php/fakepath/fakepath2/fakepath3?id=123` to 
`https://www.example.com/example.php?id=123`

Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. Do you want a URL rewrite or a redirect? The former is invisible to the user and the latter asks the user client to visit a different URL

Comment: Phil, yes i want redirect `http://www.example.com/xxx.php/fakepath/fakepath?id=123` to `http://www.example.com/xxx.php?id=123`
In PHP or Apache Server, if end user visit `http://www.example.com/xxx.php/fakepath/fakepath?id=123`, he will get same content from `http://www.example.com/xxx.php?id=123`, so I want to redirect user to correct url

Comment: @evenloooo using my answer, the user **will** _"get the same content"_. Why do you want to redirect the user to a new URL when the content will be exactly the same?

Comment: beacuse there is a lot of relative path in the PHP code, so I want to redirect user to correct url, and it may improve SEO.

Comment: @evenloooo where are these URLs coming from? Search engines only follow links

Comment: @evenloooo I've updated my answer with a _redirect_ solution. Again, you don't need `mod_rewrite`

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example.php example.php/fakepath/fakepath2/fakepath3
```